# Unexplained "NULL" in pandoc.table in ioslides

Tags: r, pandoc, rstudio

I'm attempting to use `pander::pandoc.table()` in a `ioslides` slide and I can't figure out how to get rid of the `NULL` caption at the bottom of the table.

With this example code:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=F, warning = F}
library('pander')
tab1 <- data.frame(foo=c('dog', 'cat', 'sheep', 'goat'),bar=1:4)
print(pandoc.table(tab1, caption = "Example"))
```
````

I get the following output:

[image: example]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure this is on topic here, as it seems more a Pandoc general question, rather than being related to TeX and friends.

Comment: You should not need to `print` what `pandoc.table` returns (that's why you get `NULL`), and it's also better to use the `pander` general S3 method instead of `pandoc.table`, so that you do not have to specify `results='asis'`. More details: http://blog.rapporter.net/2014/09/pander-tables-inside-of-knitr.html

Comment: @egreg -- Thanks. In the future, what would be the ideal venue for a question like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @daroczig for resolving this for me! As mentioned in his comment, by using `pander()` rather than `print(pandoc.table())`, I get the desired results. Additionally, there is no need to specify `results = 'asis'` in the chunk options when using this method. Below is the modified code:

````
```{r echo=F}
library('pander')
tab1 <- data.frame(foo=c('dog', 'cat', 'sheep', 'goat'),bar=1:4)
pander(tab1, caption = "Example")
```
````

Comment: I'm happy that I could help. Next you might have better luck at StackOverflow, the R community is pretty active there.